Why does NuGet not show all updates?
The below is a screenshot for the NuGet for a project. The Updates tab lists no packages.
But this Installed shows this package that is 2 major versions out of date. I have seen this happen before.
Is there a way to have Update show all libraries that can be updated?


you have the "only show vulnerable" checkbox enabled.

@zivkan For the Installed - yes. But for Updates it showed nothing without that checked. And even if it had been checked, this library version in use was vulnerable. So even if checked, it should have shown - shouldn't it?

Oh, I think the update tab only shows directly referenced packages, not transitive packages. If your directly referenced packages are already the latest version (or your package source selection on the top right doesn't have any version of directly referenced packages), then the list will be empty.

@zivkan Could you write that as an answer? And, include what we should do to have it update the transitive packages? Because I think it's good to update all packages. TIA

As @zivkan said, Updates tab only shows directly referenced packages, not  transitive packages. I guess it could be by-design. From looking at this Introducing Transitive Dependencies in Visual Studio, we can know that Transitive Packages in Installed tab is a new feature in VS17.3. It seems that Transitive Packages  is not supported  in Updates tab now.
You can run get-package -updates in PM command to verify it: Only Top-level packages are detected for update.
As for a workaround, you can promote this transitive dependency to a top-level dependency. This will override a resolved version to an unaffected version of a library that has a known vulnerability until a patch has been released.
After that, you could see this packages in Updates tab.
Right click this transitive package->select a new version->Install


Besides, you can also raise a feature request from here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
